# $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))\iff f(n)\sim g(n)$?

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

In [this table](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations) the two expressions $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$ ("$f$ is bounded both above and below by g asymptotically") and $f(n)\sim g(n)$ ("$f$ is equal to $g$ asymptotically") are written in two separate lines. But am I write that they mean the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No.** Constants matter.

For instance, $f(x) = x$ and $g(x)=2x$ satisfy $f(n) =\Theta(g(n))$ (for $n\to\infty$), but we do **not** have
$$
f(n) \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} g(n)\,,
$$
which would mean $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=1$.
We *do* have 
$$
f(n) \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{2}g(n)\,.
$$

*In short: $\sim$ is more refined, a strictly stronger statement. You have one implication of what you wrote, but not the equivalence.*

Comment: As additional information that would be useful for understanding $\sim$: could you give an example of $f$ and $g$ such that $f\sim g$ but $f\not=g$?

Comment: @user7280899 Sure. For instance, $x$ and $x+\sqrt{x}$; or $x$ and $\frac{1}{\log(1+1/x)}$ (at $\infty$).

Comment: Nice! Thanks!!!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps $f(n)=\Theta(g(n))$ means
$$
0 < \liminf \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \le \limsup \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} < +\infty
$$
while $f(n)\sim g(n)$ means
$$
\lim\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 1
$$

Comment: Why *"Perhaps"*?

Comment: Why perhaps?  Because different parts of mathematics may use different definitions...

Comment: The OP is specifically referring to a set of notation they linked to.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference I think, is you wouldn't say $$f(n)=n^3\sim g(n)=4n^3.$$ But $f(n)\in\Theta(g(n))$ in the case. In other words, "$\sim$" requires two functions behave almost the  **SAME**, besides being bounded above and below.